# Not found an object in coredata after added to a relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, relationship, nsfetchrequest

I have an issue with the fetch of an object after added in a relationship. The first time that i fetch the category, always found, then when i added to the relationship the following categories not found.

The relationship is a `Many-To-Many`.

Example:

- Fetch category with `categoryId = 10`
- Found category object
- Added to the parent object relationship
- Next object
- If the several categories has the same `id`, `categoryId = 10`, not found

  ```
  NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

     [private setParentContext:self.model.context];
      __block NSError *error = nil;

      [private performBlockAndWait:^{

          GPDeal *deal = [EKManagedObjectMapper objectFromExternalRepresentation:dic withMapping:[GPDeal objectMapping] inManagedObjectContext:private];
          for (NSDictionary *dic in responseObject[@"response"]) {

              GPCategory *category;

             //The first time always found
              if ((category = [GPCategory MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"catId" withValue:dic[@"mainAttribute"] inContext:private])) {
                  NSLog(@"Found");
                  [category addDealsObject:deal];

              } else {
                  NSLog(@"Not Found");

              }

          }
      }];

      NSError *PrivateError = nil;
      if (![private save:&PrivateError]) {
          NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", PrivateError, [PrivateError userInfo]);
          abort();
      }

      if (!error) {
          //Save on main moc
          [self.model saveWithErrorBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
              if (!success) {
                  NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
              }
          }];

      } else {
          NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
      }
  ```

**EDIT:**

Solved , I guess my problem was that i forgot to save the main context in the end of each iteration .

```
        NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundMOC = [self.model backgroundMOC:self.model.context];

        [backgroundMOC performBlockAndWait:^{

            for (NSDictionary *dic in responseObject[@"response"]) {

                GPDeal *deal = [EKManagedObjectMapper objectFromExternalRepresentation:dic withMapping:[GPDeal objectMapping] inManagedObjectContext:backgroundMOC];

                GPCategory *category;
                if ((category = [GPCategory MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"catId" withValue:dic[@"mainAttribute"] inContext:backgroundMOC])) {
                    NSLog(@"Found with mainAttribute %@", dic[@"mainAttribute"]);
                    [deal addDealCategoryObject:category];
                }

                if([backgroundMOC hasChanges]) {
                    NSError * error;
                    [backgroundMOC save:&error];

                    [self.model.context performBlockAndWait:^{
                        if([self.model.context hasChanges]) {
                            NSError * error;
                            [self.model.context save:&error];
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Which context does the `deal` object belong to?  It looks like it must be a different context from `private`.  You shouldn't set relationships between objects in different contexts.  Pass the managedObjectID and then retrieve it in the `private` context using `objectWithID`.

Comment: I checked already, but `deal` is created inside of the private context

Comment: so your problem is only with caregoryId = 10 ? 1st time you have 10 in dic[@"mainAttribute"] it find the category and 2nd time it doesn't? The fact that the problem might not be coming from MR_findFirstByAttribute tells me that the problem could be the string containing the integer in dic[@"mainAttribute"]. could you NSLog(@"ID:-%@-") in order to check that the ID doesn t have spaces before or after?

Comment: @Mikael Is not related with strange spaces in the ID. i check it already.
It seems  that the object has a One-To-Many relationship as i can only attach one object to the relatuionship but it is Many-To-Many 100% sure i check it like there is no tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may lack saving the MOC chain. For clarity, I have replaced the keyword `private` with the variable name `backgroundMOC`.

On the question above, I can only assume that the line `NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];`
 is technically similar to:

```m
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)backgroundMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext *)mainMOC
{
    NSManagedObjectContext * threadManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
                             initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [threadManagedObjectContext setParentContext:mainMOC];
    [threadManagedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    return threadManagedObjectContext;
}
```

passing `self.model.context` as mainMOC, with a `self.model.context` and a `setMergePolicy`.
Similarly, I must assume that `self.model saveWithErrorBlock` is technically identical to:

```
[mainMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
    if([mainMOC hasChanges]) {
        NSError * error;
        [mainMOC save:&error];
        // handle error
    }
}];
```

If so, the same should be said of the `backgroundMOC` (your `private` reference):

```
[backgroundMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
    if([backgroundMOC hasChanges]) {
        NSError * error;
        [backgroundMOC save:&error];
        // handle error
    }
}];
```

---

In other words, you want to ensure that your `backgroundMOC` and `mainMOC` save operation is executed from their respective threads, with `performBlockAndWait`.

Comment: Of concern is the thread from which you execute `performBlockAndWait` for `self.model.context save`. That should be done on the main thread, or else your `UI` (say you are using `NSFetchedResultsController`) can crash (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6913811/218152). Also, if you need to `[mainMOC save:&error]` every time you `[backgroundMOC save:&error]`, you may not need a `backgroundMOC` in the first place: the idea of `backgroundMOC` is to perform lengthy operations, which may not be the case here.  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A218152+performBlockAndWait